# What's the way to implement struct field validations in official Go mongo-driver?

Tags: mongodb, validation, go, mongo-go

I am using Go official MongoDB driver. Is there any way to validate struct fields using BSON tags, the way how GORM pkg does?

[image]

Comment: What type of validation you want to do ?

Comment: @Eklavya Document field validation. Like, can we say here `bson:"required,unique"` with tag?

Answer (score 3):

You mean as struct tags? No, not directly. And there is a good reason for that: software libraries more and more adopt the "do one thing and do it good" approach. In other words: use the right tool for the job.

But validating your structs is easy enough. You can utilize the vastly powerful [github.com/asaskevich/govalidator](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/asaskevich/govalidator?tab=doc), for example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "testing"

    "github.com/asaskevich/govalidator"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive"
)

type Author struct {
    FirstName string `valid:"stringlength(3|20)" bson:"given_name" json:"given_name"`
    LastName  string `valid:"stringlength(2|20)" bson:"surname" json:"surname"`
}

type Book struct {
    // Here, if ID is set, it needs to be a valid ObjectID
    ID     primitive.ObjectID `valid:"oid,optional" bson:"_id,omitempty" json:"_id,omitempty"`
    ISBN   string             `valid:"isbn13,optional" bson:"isbn,omitempty" json:"isbn,omitempty"`
    Title  string             `valid:"stringlength(5|20)" bson:"title" json:"title"`
    // This instructs govalidator to validate the referenced struct, even when
    // it is a pointer
    Author *Author            `valid:"" bson:"author" json:"author"`
}



// ObjectIDValidator validates whether the given type is a primitive.ObjectId
// and whether its value is valid.
// govalidator only validates a string as ObjectId, so we implement a little wrapper function...
func ObjectIDValidator(inner, outer interface{}) bool {
    oid := inner.(primitive.ObjectID)
    str := oid.Hex()
    return govalidator.IsMongoID(str)
}

// ...and add it to the validators you can use as a struct tag
func init() {
    govalidator.CustomTypeTagMap.Set("oid", govalidator.CustomTypeValidator(ObjectIDValidator))
}

func TestValidity(t *testing.T) {
    testCases := []struct {
        desc         string
        book         Book
        expectedFail bool
    }{
        {
            desc: "A book with an invalid ISBN",
            book: Book{
                ID:     primitive.NewObjectID(),
                Title:  "foobar",
                ISBN:   "abc",
                Author: &Author{FirstName: "Foo", LastName: "Bar"},
            },
            expectedFail: true,
        },
        {
            desc: "A perfectly valid (and good!) book",
            book: Book{
                ID:     primitive.NewObjectID(),
                Title:  "Neuromancer",
                ISBN:   "978-0441569595",
                Author: &Author{FirstName: "William", LastName: "Gibson"},
            },
            expectedFail: false,
        },
        {
            desc: "Still a good book, but with the title cut short",
            book: Book{
                ID:     primitive.NewObjectID(),
                Title:  "Neur",
                ISBN:   "978-0441569595",
                Author: &Author{FirstName: "William", LastName: "Gibson"},
            },
            expectedFail: true,
        },
        {
            desc: "Still a good book, only the author's name was cut short",
            book: Book{
                ID:     primitive.NewObjectID(),
                Title:  "Neuromancer",
                ISBN:   "978-0441569595",
                Author: &Author{FirstName: "W", LastName: "Gibson"},
            },
            expectedFail: true,
        },
    }
    for _, tC := range testCases {
        t.Run(tC.desc, func(t *testing.T) {
            ok, err := govalidator.ValidateStruct(tC.book)

            switch {
            case !ok && !tC.expectedFail:
                t.Errorf("%#v unexpectedly did not validate as a Book: %s", tC.book, err)
                return
            case ok && tC.expectedFail:
                t.Errorf("%#v unexpectedly validated as a Book!", tC.book)
                return
            case (!ok && tC.expectedFail) || (ok && !tC.expectedFail):
                t.Logf("Just as planned")
            }

        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Current version of mongo-go does not support validation.

The valid / processed tags are listed at [`bson@Structs`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson?tab=doc#hdr-Structs):

> The following struct tags can be used to configure behavior:

> 1. `omitempty`: If the omitempty struct tag is specified on a field, the field will not be marshalled if it is set to
>    the zero value. By default, a struct field is only considered empty if the field's type implements the Zeroer
>    interface and the IsZero method returns true. Struct fields of types that do not implement Zeroer are always
>    marshalled as embedded documents. This tag should be used for all slice and map values.

> 2. `minsize`: If the minsize struct tag is specified on a field of type int64, uint, uint32, or uint64 and the value of
>    the field can fit in a signed int32, the field will be serialized as a BSON int32 rather than a BSON int64. For other
>    types, this tag is ignored.

> 3. `truncate`: If the truncate struct tag is specified on a field with a non-float numeric type, BSON doubles unmarshalled
>    into that field will be trucated at the decimal point. For example, if 3.14 is unmarshalled into a field of type int,
>    it will be unmarshalled as 3. If this tag is not specified, the decoder will throw an error if the value cannot be
>    decoded without losing precision. For float64 or non-numeric types, this tag is ignored.

> 4. `inline`: If the inline struct tag is specified for a struct or map field, the field will be "flattened" when
>    marshalling and "un-flattened" when unmarshalling. This means that all of the fields in that struct/map will be
>    pulled up one level and will become top-level fields rather than being fields in a nested document. For example, if a
>    map field named "Map" with value map[string]interface{}{"foo": "bar"} is inlined, the resulting document will be
>    {"foo": "bar"} instead of {"map": {"foo": "bar"}}. There can only be one inlined map field in a struct. If there are
>    duplicated fields in the resulting document when an inlined field is marshalled, an error will be returned. This tag
>    can be used with fields that are pointers to structs. If an inlined pointer field is nil, it will not be marshalled.
>    For fields that are not maps or structs, this tag is ignored.

Further, you may use the tag value `-` to indicate you want to skip a given field.

If you want to perform additional validation, you may implement the [`bson.Marshaler`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson@v1.3.5?tab=doc#Marshaler) and / or [`bson.Unmarshaler`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson@v1.3.5?tab=doc#Unmarshaler) interfaces which will be called by `mongo-go` whenever a value is marshalled to / unmarshalled from bson.